# pymongo gridfs mongodb authentication fails

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I am using gridfs to store and get files from my **MongoDB** database

```
fs = gridfs.GridFS(MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@XX.XX.XX.XXX:27017/').mydb)
```

and to get a file I am using

```
file = fs.get_last_version(file_name).read()
```

On this line I get Authentication Failed exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\git\EEG\ABM\BLabPythonService\app.py", line 1039, in start_processing
    sys.stderr.flush()
  File "D:\git\EEG\ABM\BLabPythonService\process_studies.py", line 271, in start_processing
    overlay_artifacts(study)
  File "D:\git\EEG\ABM\BLabPythonService\process_studies.py", line 49, in overlay_artifacts
    edf_file = fs.get_last_version(file_name).read()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gridfs\__init__.py", line 200, in get_last_version
    return self.get_version(filename=filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gridfs\__init__.py", line 184, in get_version
    grid_file = next(cursor)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1132, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1055, in _refresh
    self.__collation))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 892, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 950, in _send_message_with_response
    exhaust)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 961, in _reset_on_error
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 99, in send_message_with_response
    with self.get_socket(all_credentials, exhaust) as sock_info:
  File "C:\Python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 168, in get_socket
    with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:
  File "C:\Python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 852, in get_socket
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 570, in check_auth
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 486, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 466, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 237, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 477, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

Everything worked fine when my mongo database didnt have authentication.

Other use of database is working fine. I have this python service that is connecting to database using `flask_pymogno` and a `c#` application that is also connecting to database using `c#`, and all connections are with the same credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was actually in my password witch contained '+' character. It is a reserved URI character. Fixed it by replacing '+' with '%2B' and it now works.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding